# How to send text to Email field within Twitter login page using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, twitter, css-selectors

The code for username text area looks like this.
It doesn’t have any id and the xpath didn’t work as well.

The element from Twitter looks like this

```
<input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" name="session[username_or_email]" spellcheck="false" type="text" dir="auto" data-focusable="true" class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-1inuy60 r-utggzx r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-1swcuj1 r-1dz5y72 r-1ttztb7 r-13qz1uu" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Email** field with in Twitter login page https://twitter.com/login you have to induce WebDriverWait for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session[username_or_email]']"))).send_keys("zeecode")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='session[username_or_email]']"))).send_keys("zeecode")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
//input[@name="session[username_or_email]" and @type="text"]
```